# $.post is not working with the submit type input

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am working on this project and i want to update the database after being clicked on the signUp button, but the $.post() is not working and i can't find any error as no error is even being shown in the firebug of the firefox, Please help me out, I'm stuck since last night on this.

Am I doing any mistake, then please help me out to find those ?

Here is my code,

**part of my script.js**

```
.............
.............
 $('#submit').click(function() {
    $.post("signup.php", function(data) {
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(response.done);
    });
});
```

signup.php

```
<?php
    $json = array("done" => "1");
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

registration.php page

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
     ..........
     ..........
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info searchBtn signUpBtn wobble-skew" value="Sign Up" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

In the js file i was alert to just checking whether post is responding or not, it it did then i have to pass the input's value using JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the normal form submission:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent normal submission
    $.post("signup.php", function(data) {
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(response.done);
    });
});
```